# Android Tab Host

Tags: android

I want to add an image to `TabHost`.
This is my code:

```
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setContent(new Intent(this, DealCities.class)).setIndicator("Deals"));
```

Comment: You make no sense. Please give more detail. Screenshots. whatever...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setContent(new Intent(this, DealCities.class)).setIndicator("tab1", this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab1_icon))
```

assuming that you have a drawable resource "tab1_icon"...

Igor